# How to grow a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2D array and I want to grow it. I have copied it into a new array but how do I fill it with the contents from the previous array?

```
if (row == data.length) {

    newData = Arrays.copyOf(data, 2 * data.length);

}
```

Comment: Use [arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int))?

Comment: Have you tried using ArrayList of ArrayList??? It is dynamic array /? WOuld make you life easy

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to grow it, and then continue manipulating it in later stages of your code?

For example:

You have an array of size 4, you put 0 1 2 3 in it, now it's full, you want to double the size, and then continue adding numbers like 7 8 9 in it.

If that's the case all you need to do is assign newData to your previous array name, which by the example above is 'data'.

```
if (row == data.length)
{  
    newData = Arrays.copyOf(data, 2*data.length);
    data = newData; //assigns the newArray to the previous variable name
}
```

If on the other hand you mentioned you wanted a 2D array. Which is an array of arrays of a certain type, then your code should work for 2D arrays too.

There will however be null values in the newly created array slots (eg you have a 2D array of ComplexNumber classes, and if you try to access those classes and call a method like GetImaginaryValue()) you will get a null exception.

As the xscanpix mentioned, your code works, if what we assume you to do is right. Please edit your question if it's not the case.

If it's not what you're looking for I apologize for misunderstanding. I'm going off by the rep you have that you're a new user to SO (like me) and might just be getting started on Java.

Answer (score 0):

How is this code not doing what you want it to do? The java API doc for `Arrays.copyOf` states that it returns:

**'a copy of the original array, truncated or padded with nulls to obtain the specified length'** (depends on the type of array)

---

**Edit:**

Please post more code or it will be hard to give a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

What does this sentence mean?
"I have copied it into a new array but how do I fill it with the contents from the previous array"

You can try following line to realize this task. dataStart corresponds to the starting position in the source array and newDataStart corresponds to the starting position in the destination array.

```
System.arraycopy(data, dataStart, newData, newDataStart, data.length);
```

If you need to extend your array dynamically, you may take a look at [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) or [Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html).